# How does source encoding apply within string literals?

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding

[PEP-263](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) specifies that encoding specified in the source is applied in the following order:

> 1. read the file
> 2. decode it into Unicode assuming a fixed per-file encoding
> 3. convert it into a UTF-8 byte string
> 4. tokenize the UTF-8 content
> 5. compile it, creating Unicode objects from the given Unicode data
>      and creating string objects from the Unicode literal data
>      by first reencoding the UTF-8 data into 8-bit string data
>      using the given file encoding

So, if I take this code:

```
print 'abcdefgh'
print u'abcdefgh'
```

And convert it to ROT-13:

```
# coding: rot13

cevag 'nopqrstu'
cevag h'nopqrstu'
```

I would expect that it is first decoded and then becomes identical to the original, printing:

```
abcdefgh
abcdefgh
```

But instead, it prints:

```
nopqrstu
abcdefgh
```

So, the `unicode` literal works as expeced, but `str` remains unconverted. **Why?**

---

**Eliminating some possibilities:**

I confirmed that the problem is not in a later phase (printing to console), but immediately at parsing, becuase this code produces *"ValueError: unsupported format character 'q' (0x71) at index 1"*:

```
x = '%q' % 1  # that is %d !
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the last point actually explains what happens quite accurately:

> 5. compile it, creating Unicode objects from the given Unicode data and
>      creating string objects from the Unicode literal data by first
>      reencoding the UTF-8 data into 8-bit string data using the given file
>      encoding

After the first 4 steps, the contents of the source file are a tokenized unicode version of the following string:

```
print 'abcdefgh'
print u'abcdefgh'
```

After that, in step 5, the string object `'abcdefgh'` is *reencoded into 8-bit string data using the given file encoding* (which is rot13), so the contents become:

```
print 'nopqrstu'
print u'abcdefgh'
```

Comment: Did you answer 2 years later because I have just added your question in my favorite today? I was thinking about it a few hours ago and testing on my terminal, and boum! an answer. Thank you anyway. I came here in the first place because I was trying to understand what the step 5 meant.

Comment: @Maggyero Yeah, I got a notification about the question and decided I knew the answer :D

Comment: So to sum up (correct me if I am wrong): the tokenizer only takes UTF-8 strings as input. So the source code needs to be transcoded to UTF-8, that is to say decoded from the declared source code encoding and encoded to UTF-8. However *byte string literals* in the source code will also get decoded in the process, though they should not (but at this stage we do not know their class yet), since they are literal. That’s why at step 5 they get reencoded to the declared source code encoding. By the way, a last thing that remains unclear, what is the output of the tokenizer: Unicode or UTF-8 strings?